# How to get foreign key id instead of referenced model in Django serializers

Tags: django, django-views, django-serializer

I'm really new to Django, but one in our projects we have a Django backend, and no one else would like to touch it, so I have to make little tweaks on that.
Models set up, everything work fine, but we need a new view, where
we need basic data about one of our models, without referenced models (only the foreign key id is needed). I've spent a day with search for a solution. Maybe it's so trivial, it hasn't written anywhere :)

Models:

```
class Row(models.Model):
    row = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    height = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=36, unique = True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Row, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Column(models.Model):
    col = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    width = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    key = models.CharField(max_length=36, unique = True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Column, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Product(models.Model):

    key = models.CharField(max_length=36, unique = True)

    text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    column = models.ForeignKey(Column, db_column='column_key', to_field='key', related_name="products")
    row  = models.ForeignKey(Row, db_column='row_key', to_field='key', related_name="products")
    merged_with = models.ForeignKey("Product", db_column='merged_with_key', to_field='key', related_name="merges", blank=True, null=True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', null=True)
```

Now i need a list of products from a view, with the json output looks like:

```
{
    id: 1,
    key: "1746495d-8ea0-42df-9ed9-06df621ef7c5",
    column_key: "<key of refrenced column>"
    merged_with_key: "<key of refrenced product>"
    row_key: "<key of refrenced row>"
    text: "sometext"
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Csaba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is simple extension of ModelSerializer. 
Whose definition will look something like this.

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = ('id','key', 'column', 'merged_with', 'row', 'text')
```

And a new view like this.

```
class ProductListView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        return Response(ProductSerializer(Products.objects.all(), many=True).data)
```

You will have to map the urls to this view and import the necessary dependencies.

Your output will look slightly different with serializer as like.

```
{
    id: 1,
    key: "1746495d-8ea0-42df-9ed9-06df621ef7c5",
    column: "<key of refrenced column>"
    merged_with: "<key of refrenced product>"
    row: "<key of refrenced row>"
    text: "sometext"
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. The result is that, what we wanted :)
But analyzing the queries executed in the backend, I realized that, all foreign key record is read. So now <product number>*3 queries run instead of 1. How to block that, when I don't need referenced objects?
I know, maybe it's another question...

Comment: Ahh Not sure but can you try changing the fields from  'column', 'merged_with', 'row', to  'column_id', 'merged_with_id', 'row_id',

Comment: No, that's not working. Get:
Field name `row_key` is not valid for model `Product`
I will start another question. Thanks for your answer again. That solved the original problem.

Comment: You should use `queryset.select_related(<foreign keys fields names>)`